# Web API 2 OWIN Bearer token authentication with Dependency Injection Not working

Tags: authentication, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I need to create a Web API 2 project with token based authentication and also implement Dependency Injection in all Controllers including default `AccountController`.

Following these steps

- Using Visual Studio 2013
- Create New ASP.Net Web Application (Framework 4.5)
- Select Web API
- Authentication set to Individual User Accounts

I referred my Services and Contracts class dlls and packages

PM > Install-Package Unity

PM > Install-Package Unity.WebApi

Altered `Unity.config`

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();
        var section = LoadUnityConfigurationFile();
        section.Configure(container, "parent");
        ////section.Containers.Default.Configure(container);
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUnityContainer), container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }



private static UnityConfigurationSection LoadUnityConfigurationFile()
    {
        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        return section;
    }
```

I have added a `unity.config` file under folder config for mapping my controllers and dlls (That has been specified in the above code)

```
<containers>
        <container name="parent">
          <types>
            <type type= "PROJ.API.Services.Data.IAsUser, PROJ.API.Services"
                mapTo="PROJ.API.Services.Data.AsUser, PROJ.API.Services"></type>
            <type type="PROJ.API.Services.Contracts.IUserServices, PROJ.API.Services.Contracts"mapTo="PROJ.API.Services.Business.UserServices, PROJ.API.Services"></type>
            <type type="PROJ.API.Controllers.AccountController, PROJ.API"
                  mapTo="PROJ.API.Controllers.AccountController, PROJ.API" ></type>
            <type type="PROJ.API.Controllers.HomeController, PROJ.API"
                  mapTo="PROJ.API.Controllers.HomeController, PROJ.API" ></type>

          </types>
        </container>
      </containers>
```

I added a controller `UserController` for getting user details. Thats working fine

```
public class UserController : ApiController
        {

            public UserController(IUnityContainer container)
            {
                this.UnityContainer = container;
            }
            public IUnityContainer UnityContainer { get; set; }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("Get")]
            public ServiceResponseDto<UserDto> GetUserDetails()
            {
                var userServices = this.UnityContainer.Resolve<IUserServices>();
                return userServices.GetUserDetails();
            }
    }
```

After adding these control, the default `AccountController` has stopped its working.

When I uncomment the line `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();`  from `Global.asax`, that's working fine

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();  
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

How to add Dependency Injection in `AccountController` ?

```
 namespace AUB.API.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
        public class AccountController : ApiController
        {
            private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
            private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

            public AccountController()
            {
            }

            public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
            {
                UserManager = userManager;
                AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
            }

            public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
            {
                get
                {
                return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                }
                private set
                {
                _userManager = value;
                }
            }

            public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }

            // GET api/Account/UserInfo
            [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
            [Route("UserInfo")]
            public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
            {
                ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

                return new UserInfoViewModel
                {
                    Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
                    HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
                    LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

I need all account related functionalities in `AccountController` including Dependency Injection. Please help

Comment: Wow, lots of cases of `NotWorkingException` these days. I feel sorry for you. (Instead of saying "not working" you should describe the actual problem.)

Comment: Explained. Please help

Comment: Sorry but that is still not an explanation. *What* is not working and *how*?

Comment: I called http://localhost:60921/api/User/Get    then, debugging possible and code working fine. Then call http://localhost:60921/api/Account/UserInfo   (or any url) debugger didn't comes to AccountController. I got Error 500.